# Invoke-SPOSiteSwap: SwapSite operation not yet supported

Tags: sharepoint-online

We are planning to release our company-wide intranet site by the end of this month. I already have created a home page and the URL of the site is like https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/something. But I'd like to have the homepage as https://companyname.sharepoint.com. I tried Invoke-SPOSiteSwap, but I get "Invoke-SPOSiteSwap: SwapSite operation not yet supported". I already installed the latest SharePoint Admin PowerShell from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588 So this proves that this feature is not pushed to our tenant. I read somewhere to request Microsoft to push this feature to our tenant. Is this possible? If not, is there any other way to move/swap my approved Communication site to https://companyname.sharepoint.com url?

Answer (score 1):

I opened a ticket with Microsoft to find an alternate solution for this. This feature is available only at the end of February for a tenant with users 10,000 or more. That sais they don't have any other solution other than to wait.